# Logarithm checking my work.

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

$\ln e^{2x}=6$

2x=6

x=3

Is this method correct. ln$e$ cancel into 1.

Comment: yes this is right $\log_{a}{a}=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because the ln of a number is the power to which you have to raise e to get that number, and the power you have to raise e to to get e is 1.